# Generate a sequence of number which excludes 4 and 8

Tags: php

Trying but could not make it work being a newcomer to programming.

How to Generate a sequence of numbers from 1 to 9999 which excludes 4 and 8 digits in the number and the sum of all digits of the resultant number should also not equal to 4 or 8

e.g. 2356 is valid number as it doesn't contain 4 or 8 and the sum of all numbers is 2+3+5+6 = 16; 1+6=7. Therefore 7 doesn't contain 4 or 8

Likewise generate all valid numbers from 0 to 9999

Comment: does it random number or sequence?

Comment: @Dipakchavda it's sequence from 1 to 9999

Comment: so you wants in loop right from 1 to 9999 right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.It should work fine

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<2357;$i++)
{
    $array = str_split($i);
    a: $tempSum = array_sum($array);
    if($tempSum > 10)
    {
        $tempVal = array_sum($array);
        $array = str_split($tempVal);
        goto a;
    }
    if(array_sum($array) !=4 && array_sum($array) !=8 && !in_array(4,str_split($i))  && !in_array(8,str_split($i)))
    {
        echo $i;
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}

?>
```

Here am printing number till 2357 you can change it to any maximum number you require.

Comment: Thanks for help. But number containing 4 and 8 digits should also be excluded from the loop.

Comment: Now code is updated to exclude numbers which has 4 and 8.

Comment: accept it as an answer if it solves your problem, this will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward, although not very efficient:

```
<?php

for ($num=1;$num<10000;$num++) {

    $thousands = intval($num/1000);
    $hundreds = intval(($num - $thousands * 1000)/100);
    $tens = intval(($num - $thousands * 1000 - $hundreds * 100)/10);
    $units = $num - $thousands * 1000 - $hundreds * 100 - $tens * 10;

    $digits_sum = $thousands + $hundreds + $tens + $units;
    while ($digits_sum >= 10) {
        $digits_sum = intval($digits_sum / 10) + ($digits_sum % 10);
    }

    if ($thousands != 4 && $thousands != 8 &&
        $hundreds != 4 && $hundreds != 8 &&
        $tens != 4 && $tens != 8 &&
        $units != 4 && $units != 8 &&
        ($digits_sum != 4) && ($digits_sum != 8)
    ) {
        echo $num."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: this code won't work when $thousands+$hundreds+$tens+$units>=10 as in that case you need to sum the digits of that sum and compare that to 4 or 8.

Comment: @Nick The requirement is "the sum of all digits of the resultant number should also not equal to 4 or 8", with "resultant number" being 1 to 9999. Why can't the sum be 10 or larger? If we are to further sum the digits of the sum, this is a different requirement altogether - namely that the sum must be a single digit number.

Comment: That requirement is in the original post with his example of 2356, where the digit sum is 16 and he then further sums 1+6 to 7 to decide the number is valid.

Comment: @Nick Right. I missed the example. I now edited the code to handle that too.

Comment: @IamTheWalrus. Thanks man. This works well for my requirement.